# Parse A Text In A Text File With Python

Tags: python, file, string-parsing

I use the '/' special character to split each word in the text file. The code output is as follows:

```
Mariam / AI / DS / ML 

Steeve / DM / CO / DBMS / ML 

Peter / DS / CO / MDS / ML 

Stella / AI / DS / ML / DSAD 

Martin / AI / ML / DS / MDS
```

I'm aiming to separate every word in the file. The code I developed to solve this problem is available below:

```py
import os

desktop = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop")
filePath = os.path.join(desktop, "inputPS13.txt")
file2 = open(filePath)
line1=file2.readline()
print("file is opened")

while(line1!=""):
    print(line1)
    line1=file2.readline()
   
for line in file2:
    for word in line.split("/"):
           print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as file:

    # read file and remove new line characters
    lines = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]

    # remove empty strings
    lines = [line for line in lines if not line == ""]

for line in lines:

    # prints a list of of every word in a line
    print(line.split(" / "))
```